# Using *args in a for loop doesn't take into account changing variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have long loops for deduping names, and I was hoping to simplify things by using a function rather than repeating all the carry-on effects of a match each time. I'm starting with the following test case, but it doesn't work like I expect:

```
x, y = 0, 0
def testFunc(*args):
    global x, y
    for arg in args:
        if arg:
            x +=1
        else:
            y +=1
    return (x, y)
```

When I run it:

```
>>>testFunc(x==y,x==y,x==y)
(3,0)
>>>testFunc(x==y)
(3,1)
>>>testFunc(x!=y,x!=y,x!=y)
(3,4)
```

Basically, the arguments seem to be transformed into boolean before any operation happens. Is there a way to avoid that? I would have expected:

```
>>>testFunc(x==y,x==y,x==y)
(2,1)
>>>testFunc(x==y)
(2,2)
>>>testFunc(x!=y,x!=y,x!=y)
(4,3)
```

Comment: No, parameters will be evaluated before the function executes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Basically, the arguments seem to be transformed into boolean before any operation happens.

Python first evaluates the arguments before calling the function, so this is the expected behaviour. The equality of two `int`s is a `bool`ean. So it first evaluates `x == y` three times, each time yielding the same result. Next it calls the function with `testFunc(True, True, True)`.

> Is there a way to avoid that?

You can make it a callable, and thus *postpone* evaluation, with:

```
def testFunc(*args):
    global x, y
    for arg in args:
        if arg():  # we call arg
            x +=1
        else:
            y +=1
    return (x, y)
```

and then calling it with:

```
>>> eq = lambda: x == y
>>> neq = lambda: x != y
>>> testFunc(eq, eq, eq)
(2, 1)
>>> testFunc(eq)
(2, 2)
>>> testFunc(neq, neq, neq)
(3, 4)
```

Here we thus do *not* pass the result of `x == y`, we pass a function that, when called, *calculates* the result of `x == y`. As a result the value is calculates for `x` and `y` at the moment when the call is made.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `x==y` tests for equality, and will only yield a boolean. To assign your variable, just use one `=` sign.

For example:

`1==3` yields `False`, therefore `x==y` will do the same unless `x` and `y` are explicitly the same

`testFunc(x=y)` should solve your problem. Furthermore, `*args` implies a list of arguments:

```
def myFunc(*args):
    for arg in args:
         print(arg)
```

Will take `myFunc(*[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` and `print` each member of that list. Note, you will need the `*<list>` syntax, otherwise `myFunc(<list>)` will have the list be the first and only argument. The `*` unpacks the values from the list